# A website failed to charge my visa gift card AFTER I was already given services-- What happens next?

Tags: visa

I bought a virtual currency with a visa gift card, and then spent said currency.

However, they failed to charge the visa gift card for the necessary amount, and terminated the account until an alternate payment method is used.

The balance on the card has remained the same.

I typically only use visa gift cards for this type of service, and they approved the transaction beforehand.

What happens now? How are they able to seize the funds, given that the site has no other information about me.

I actually read the terms of service, and the part relevant to this issue reads:

"If we do not receive payment via your payment method for Your use of the Service, You agree to pay all amounts due upon demand by us. Each time You use the Service, You agree and reaffirm that we are authorized to charge or make a transfer related to your billing method. If we do not receive the full amount of Your account balance within thirty (30) days of the invoice date, an additional 1.5% (or the highest amount allowed by law, whichever is lower) per month late charge may be added to Your bill and immediately become due and payable, in our sole discretion. You shall be liable for all attorney fees and collection fees arising from our efforts to collect any past due and unpaid balance of Your account.
You agree to be billed for and to pay any outstanding balance in the event of cancellation or termination of Your account. Unless You notify us of any discrepancies within thirty (30) days after they first appear on Your account statement, they will be deemed acceptable by You for all purposes, including resolution of inquiries made by Your card issuer or bank. You release us and all our representatives from all liabilities and claims of loss resulting from any error or discrepancy that is not reported to us within thirty (30) days of its publication."

Can somebody translate?

Comment: Translation: You have to pay, or they will *try* to go after you, making you pay the original amount + interest + fees. If they *succeed* in going after you is a whole different story, though, given that they have very little information about you.

Comment: What happens next is that you contact them and offer them an alternate means of payment. Their ability to *seize* the money only comes into play if you are willing to violate the contract (and possibly the law) but since you are not trying to con them, you don't need to worry about that, right?

Answer (score 1):

> Can somebody translate?

You need to pay; else they may charge interest and / or engage legal / collection agencies and any charges incurred for these services will also be collected by them.

> What happens now? How are they able to seize the funds, given that the site has no other information about me

This depends on what amount they have and how serious they are. There are multiple ways to try and find you if the amounts are large; i.e. trace the virtual currency transaction or your i.p. address; some of this may need legal documents that they may obtain via court order / judgment.

What you should do is contact them and mention that the card is not charged. This way is shows your intent to pay and its their mistake they have not collected the funds.